# .on(click) event fires on fixed position element when scrolling on IOS mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a function that triggers when an li element or menu is clicked that slides the nav container left the width of the window. For some reason in my iPhone after i trigger the initial click to slide the container off screen,   If I scroll up or down the event gets triggers again and again every time i scroll. The event should only fire when my menu button or li element is clicked. I noticed it has something to do with position:fixed on the header that contains the menu. If i take the position fixed off, it works fine. What can i do to keep my position fixed without triggering the click event every time I scroll on iOS device

here's a link to the site http://www.lunacarpentry.com/peachietouch

Answer (score 0):

Your link is dead. Also, the problem was probably stemming from the fact that your screen height changes on a iphone by 44px depending on the bottom tool bar. I solve this problem by binding prevent default to the `touchmove` when anything animates on to my screen. Then make sure the bottom:0; as well as top and left.